# Start Spring RESTful webservice through Vaadin application

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc, spring-boot, vaadin

I've implemented a Sping Boot Maven project using one class with `@RestController`. I configured this application to use port `9000` as the normal Vaadin application uses port 8082. What I want to achieve is, to start the REST-Application project through a class of the Vaadin application project. The main class for the Spring application is called `RestServiceApplication` containing the annotation `@SpringBootApplication`. No I just call

```
SpringApplication sa = new SpringApplication(SenAalRestServiceApplication.class);
    sa.run(args);
```

to run the RESTful webservice.

Now my problem is, that I can't call any method in the REST service. The log output of Spring startup just says:

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.3.1.RELEASE)

2016-01-15 14:10:30.907  INFO 7900 --- [nio-8082-exec-1] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Starting application on Kampfkeks with PID 7900 (C:\Users\Marcel\Desktop\ENTWICKLUNG_JAVA\java\workspaces\RaspAAL\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\SenAAL\WEB-INF\lib\spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar started by Marcel in C:\Users\Marcel\Desktop\ENTWICKLUNG_JAVA\java\eclipse)
2016-01-15 14:10:30.913  INFO 7900 --- [nio-8082-exec-1] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2016-01-15 14:10:31.020  INFO 7900 --- [nio-8082-exec-1] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@1c9710d: startup date [Fri Jan 15 14:10:31 CET 2016]; root of context hierarchy
2016-01-15 14:10:34.320  INFO 7900 --- [nio-8082-exec-1] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2016-01-15 14:10:34.340  INFO 7900 --- [nio-8082-exec-1] o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Starting beans in phase 0
2016-01-15 14:10:34.540  INFO 7900 --- [nio-8082-exec-1] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Started application in 4.126 seconds (JVM running for 18.913)
```

EDIT:
Okay, I explain this in more detail: 
I've got two applications:
1. Vaadin application NOT Spring powered, just running in a NORMAL Tomcat container (server).
2. Spring Boot Application containing a main class and a RestController.

In projec 1. I've got a class which just calls the above mentioned

```
SpringApplication sa = new SpringApplication(SenAalRestServiceApplication.class);
    sa.run(args);
```

After launching the Vaadin app and calling this code fragment, the Spring Boot application will startup, but it will never show any REST service available. I think there is too little log output at the moment for a Spring Boot application. I played around with the log level, but it is still the same.

Now what I've done is, removed the dependency to project 2. ind project 1. and copied all sources of project 2. into project 1. and tried to run the Spring Boot application directly in project 1. My problem here is, that the embedded Tomcat server/container couldn't be started. I get the following error. What's the problem here??? I am starting the Spring Boot application within the Vaadin application with the same mentioned code fragment.

```
2016-01-16 11:59:29.025  WARN 1060 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: loader (instance of org/apache/catalina/loader/WebappClassLoader) previously initiated loading for a different type with name "org/apache/catalina/Service"
2016-01-16 11:59:29.039 ERROR 1060 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: loader (instance of org/apache/catalina/loader/WebappClassLoader) previously initiated loading for a different type with name "org/apache/catalina/Service"
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:133) ~[EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.class:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:532) ~[AbstractApplicationContext.class:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118) ~[EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.class:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:764) ~[SpringApplication.class:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.doRun(SpringApplication.java:357) ~[SpringApplication.class:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:305) ~[SpringApplication.class:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at de.hska.iwi.senaal.service.rest.SenAALRestCallback.<init>(SenAALRestCallback.java:24) [SenAALRestCallback.class:na]
    at de.hska.iwi.senaal.service.SenAALService.<init>(SenAALService.java:117) [SenAALService.class:na]
    at de.hska.iwi.senaal.factory.SenAALFactoryImpl.getSenAALService(SenAALFactoryImpl.java:56) [SenAALFactoryImpl.class:na]
    at de.hska.iwi.senaal.servlet.MainServlet.servletInitialized(MainServlet.java:43) [MainServlet.class:na]
    at com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.init(VaadinServlet.java:216) [VaadinServlet.class:7.6.0.alpha2]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1241) [catalina.jar:8.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1154) [catalina.jar:8.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:827) [catalina.jar:8.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:135) [catalina.jar:8.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106) [catalina.jar:8.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:506) [catalina.jar:8.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142) [catalina.jar:8.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [catalina.jar:8.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610) [catalina.jar:8.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88) [catalina.jar:8.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:537) [catalina.jar:8.0.14]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1081) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.14]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:658) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.14]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.14]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1566) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.14]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1523) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.14]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_31]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_31]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-util.jar:8.0.14]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_31]
```

Comment: shift your vaadin servlet down one url.  e.g. `vaadin.servlet.urlMapping=/vaadinapp/*` with vaadin4spring/springvadin

Comment: @cfrick That did not work.

Comment: please add in your question, how you are integrating vaadin in your app.  also crank up the log levels for spring and vaadin to see what mappings are actually used etc.

Comment: @cfrick Hmmm....I think the application is not starting properly. If i start the Spring Boot application on it's own, it is working great and there is a little more log output. I don't know what to do.

Comment: From your description it sound like you'd like to start the spring context for your REST app from inside the Vaadin app but your setup/requirement is a bit unclear at this point. Is the Vaadin app configured and started in the same spring context as the REST service? Why would you like to start it from the Vaadin app?

Comment: @Morfic The Vaadin application runs in a normal Servlet Container within Tomcat 8. I need to instantiate the REST Spring Boot application from a java class in this Vaadin application.

Comment: Can you explain why you need this to happen and how are the 2 apps packaged? For example if both are spring apps and packaged together, you could create the REST context as a child for the Vaadin app. If they're package individually (or don't share a classpath) you may need to think about including all the libraries required to run the REST app, etc

Comment: @Morfic I've explained it in more detail.

Comment: At this point, it would help a lot if you could share a stripped down [sscce](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22754/sscce-how-to-provide-examples-for-programming-questions) version of your project (remove any sensitive info) or just start a new one with a similar config, to illustrate the problem (either on github or any such service you are comfortable with)